# ValueError: hour must be in 0..23

Tags: python, date, datetime

I am working on making a system for a library in Python. I am currently working on a function that will test if the user has books that are due, but I am getting the error `ValueError: hour must be in 0..23`.

Dict "users":

```py
users = {
    "djoh01": {
        "password": "johndoe1",
        "books": [{"duedate": {"year": 2021, "month": 1, "day": 4}}],
    }
}
```

Python:

```py
def checkMissingBooks(username):
    global users
    try:
        books = users[username]["books"]  # get users book list
    except:  # error getting list of books
        return False  # they have never checked out a book as the list can not be found
    for book in books:
        if (
            datetime.time(
                book["duedate"]["year"],
                book["duedate"]["month"],
                book["duedate"]["day"],
            )
            < datetime.date.today()
        ):
            return True
```

How can I get this working?

Comment: Why are you trying to construct a `datetime.time` out of a year, month, and date?  Do you maybe want `datetime.date`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`datetime.time` returns time, use `datetime.date` instead, see [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html), as:

```
....
if datetime.time(book["duedate"]["year"], book["duedate"]["month"], book["duedate"]["day"]) < datetime.date.today():
```

Comment: I will accept this as an answer as soon as stackoverflow will let me.

Answer (score 2):

It's looking for a time (with an *hour* between 00 and 23) since you are using `datetime.time`. You want to use `datetime.date` instead.

```
...
if datetime.date(book["duedate"]["year"], book["duedate"]["month"], book["duedate"]["day"]) < datetime.date.today():
      return True
```

returns `True` with your function for the username `"djoh01"`.